# I need to pass the csv values to the http request for single user

Tags: csv, jmeter

I have csv data set config of locations and i need to pass those to http request in single run for each user i.e if i have 4 locations then i need the http request to be called 4 times wherein those locations are passed one by one sequentially.
HTTP REQUEST:[https://api.drivevegas.k8.devfactory.com/rest/acdr?latitude=${Latitude}&longitude=${Longitude}&heading=0&speed=0&course=90&sequence=1670427622&carCategories=REGULAR](https://api.drivevegas.k8.devfactory.com/rest/acdr?latitude=$%7BLatitude%7D&longitude=$%7BLongitude%7D&heading=0&speed=0&course=90&sequence=1670427622&carCategories=REGULAR)
The latitude and longitude are passed form csv file

Latitude,Longitude
36.10803655487475,-115.16748588704128
36.10805389068134,-115.16570490025539
36.106112256560955,-115.16570490025539
36.10547081331421,-115.16656320714016
36.10546214512636,-115.16748588704128
36.097084543359564,-115.17586335211487

Answer (score 0):

You should use csv data set config, here is a link that may come handy
https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG

Answer (score 0):

1. Add [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) somewhere, i.e. as a child of the HTTP Request and provide full or relative path to your CSV file in the "Filename" field:

   [image]
2. In the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler refer the variables from CSV as `${Latitude}` and `${Longitude}` where required, i.e. in the Parameters tab:

   [image]
3. That's it, with default [Sharing Mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-csv-dataset-config) setting of the CSV Data Set Config JMeter will pick up the next line on each iteration of each thread (virtual user) and substitute [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) placeholders with the respective values from the CSV file

   [image]